# Python openpyxl date incorrectly formatted in xlsx/Excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a problem with the correct formatting via openpyxl in Excel.
I have a date string in Python (e.g. "11.12.2022"), which I convert into a correct date format (from my point of view) with NamedStyle from openpyxl and output as xlsx. In Excel, the data type date is then displayed for this value, but the value does not behave like a date. Only when I click in the cell with the date in Excel and confirm with 'Enter' is the value actually recognized as a date.
Please see the screenshots before and after I confirmed the value with 'Enter' (the Date in cell A4 is slightly shifted to the right, as it behaves now like a date):

[image: Date in Excel before pressing Enter]
[image: Date in Excel before pressing Enter]
[image]

I am using the German Excel version.

Here is a sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle

# Change directory
directory = r'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Test Date'
os.chdir(directory)

# Create dataframe
data = {
        'Date': ["21.02.2024", "13.07.2023", "11.12.2022"],
        'Test': [16.46, 17.21, 14.98]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a date format for the excel output
date_format = NamedStyle(name='date_format', number_format='DD.MM.YYYY')

# Create an Excel file with several sheets
output_file = directory + "/Output.xlsx"
with pd.ExcelWriter(output_file, engine='openpyxl') as writer: # Specify engine='openpyxl'
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Test_Output', index=False)
    
    # Access the sheet
    workbook = writer.book
    sheet = writer.sheets['Test_Output']
    
    # Iterate through the cells in the first column of the sheet and format the dates
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=1, max_col=1):
        for cell in row:
            # Convert the cell contents into an excel date
            try:
                cell.style = date_format
            except ValueError:
                pass
```

Does anyone have an idea why the date does not work?

Comment: In Excel, dates are formatted *numbers*. You have text. What happens when you use `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)`?

Comment: Btw, `ExcelWriter` has `date_format` and `datetime_format` parameters.

Comment: I.e .Change the Dates from string to datetime in your DataFrame and they will be written as datetime to Excel. Even `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` will probably work. Otherwise try `df["Date"] = df["Date"].apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)`

Comment: Excel doesn't have a very good conception of dates and datetimes and is, therefore unreliable: e.g. "0" is also "1900-01-01". Using datetimes with a suitable number format is best way to avoid problems. Or text, which avoids the problems of 15-digit precison.